# Can't make downloadable a file

Tags: php, xml, extjs, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm getting troubles with the download from a server. If I enter to http://mypage.com can't download some .zip files. But if I enter to the page's IP, I download the files.

Other similar issue i'm having is with Godaddy, can't make my zip downloads even if I access with the IP or domain.

This is part of the code to generate the XML and ZIP it:

```
**xmlzip.php**
    $xmlfile = $rfc.$year.$month.'BN.xml';
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $el_xml = $xml->saveXML();
    $xml->save($xmlfile);

    $filename = $rfc.$year.$month.'BN';
    shell_exec('zip ../'.$filename.' '.$xmlfile);

    try {
      $date= date('Ymd_Hi');
      $data = '{
          "filename":"xml'.$date.'.zip",
          "filename2":"'.$filename.'.zip"
      }';
      echo '{"success":1,"message":"ok","data":['.$data.']}';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $data = '';
      echo '{"error":1,"message":"error","data":['.$data.']}';
      die();
    }
```

Then I get this on ExtJS to create the Messagebox.wait :

```
**downloadzip button**
     msg = Ext.MessageBox.wait('Generating XML ...', '');
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'cakephp/app/webroot/xml.php?',
            params:{
                rfc: rfc,
                month: month,
                year: year
            },
            method : "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            jsonData: true,
            timeout: 1000000,
            withCredentials: true,
            success : function(response) {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                filename = jsonResponse.data[0].filename;
                filename2 = jsonResponse.data[0].filename2;

                if(jsonResponse.success === 1) {
                    msg.hide();
                    Ext.getCmp("winFormXML_XMLpanel").setHtml(
                        '<iframe id="" name=""'+
                        ' src="cakephp/app/webroot/download_xml.php?filename='+
                        filename+'&filename2='+filename2+'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
                    Ext.getCmp('winFormXML').destroy();
                } else {
                    msg.hide();
                    Ext.Msg.alert("ERROR","Error generating XML.");
                }

            },
            failure : function(response) {
                msg.hide();
                var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                console.log(respObj);
                Ext.Msg.alert("ERROR", respObj.status.statusMessage);
            }
        });
```

And with this i download the generated file:

```
**downloadzip.php**
    try {
        $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
        $filename2 = $_REQUEST['filename2'];

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename2);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename2));
        readfile($filename2);
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex-getMessage();
    }
```

Like i mention above, I know it works because I can download it from other computers but via IP, and not from the domain.

---

**EDIT:**

It seems that the line `Ext.getCmp('winFormXML').destroy();` was giving troubles when generating. Removing that line make it works!

Comment: Hope I'm not wrong, but generally, if you have a problem with URL that is resolved when you use an IP adress, it's probably a problem of [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Function) or [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Purpose).Try to open a command prompt command and ping the URL mypage.com, if you don't see the correct IP adress in the command result/output, try to check your DNS or hosts file. Another thing, don't launch php script inside your cakephp webroot folder, it's a security issue/breach.

Comment: upvote cuz of you're answer. thanks! first of all, pinged to mypage.com and its the correct IP. other issue i've detectedis that when i click on the downloadxml button, my downloadzip.php gets red (error/warning) in both ways, i mean also when the download works in the Network tab.Request Headers shows: `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1`. And got no Preview or Response. In Timing got Stalled at 21.00 ms. Any ideas? :( . Btw where's  the best path to put the php scripts?

Answer (score 1):

"**Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1**" mean that your browser is asking to your server to transform the url (http) to a secure url (https).

And for the best path for your logic, create a little cakeph plugin (maybe the plugin [exist](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp)) or just use a controller (like pagesController or dedicated one) and create inside this controller an action (function) that will do all the job that you need (action on xml file, zip and download)

*Like this you can add a security layer (for example to only let authenticated user download your file), you can also add some statistics (save downloaded counter in your database)*

And i'm not sure that using shell_exec is a good practise, instead this, try **ziparchive**
An example of useful [cakephp zip helper](https://github.com/tim-kos/CakePHP-Zip-Helper/blob/master/zip.php)
or like this

```
<?php

...

$filename2 = 'xml.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($filename2, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{
    die("zip creation failed!");
} else {
    $zip->addFile($xmlfile);
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename2);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename2));
    readfile($filename2);
    unlink($filename2);
}
?>
```

And at last for your issue if you didn't have the Upgrade-Insecure-Requests message when you use IP adress, it mean that the problem come from your browser. Try to use a browser that don't implement this security level (like chrome or firefox) or simply configure your website to work with https protocol:
 -> redirection in your .htaccess (inside your cakephp root directory)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(s|g)etcmd?(.+)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)http(\:|\%3A)(.*)$
    ReWriteRule .* - [F]    

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

-> and some configuration in you virtual host to listen on port 443 (inside /etc/apache2/site-available if your under *nix)

```
# with the automatic HTTPS redirection you are not supposed to configure HTTP part (port 80)
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mypage.com
    ServerName mypage.com
    ServerAlias mypage.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage
    <Directory /var/www/mypage/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerSignature Off
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@mypage.com
    ServerName mypage.com
    ServerAlias mypage.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage
    <Directory /var/www/mypage/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerSignature Off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    # If you have secure certificate
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificats/YOURCRTFILE.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificats/YOURPEMFILE.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certificats/YOURPEMFILE.pem
    SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificats/YOURCRTFILE.crt
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for you're anwser! I'm relative new developing, and because of the time, i used a php instead of controller (and because i've failed in doing that). For the ZIP generation, i used ziparchive but tryed shell_exec to try to solve my trouble. But now that i've solved that, and based on what you say, i'll put it back replacing shell_exec. And one last thing, can you help me with an example on how to create an xml and zip on a cakephp/controller?

Comment: which version of cakephp?

Comment: Sorry for the late! I'm on version 2.6.1